# Three diodes in series AC detection

Tags: diodes, ac, series

Why, in the circuit shown [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/221027), would you put three diodes in series with one another instead of using one diode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It reads in the answer. To get enough voltage to be able to turn on the optocoupler LED.